# Is there a way to search by column with Shiny's updated DT::renderDataTable and DT::dataTableOutput?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Shiny seems to have changed the implementation of data tables. What was the reason for this?

Unless I'm missing something, the new default looks like a step backwards. For one thing, they are missing the column-specific search boxes at the bottom of the table. Is there a way to replace that functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly still exists, it just seems to not be the default anymore.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(cars, filter = "top")
  }
))
```

I just went to the website docs for datatable at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ and on the front page they say how to use the `filter` parameter

Make sure you're using the most up to date version of both shiny and DT (use the GitHub version because a lot of work was done in the past 2 weeks)